# How to resolve "Error getting response: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: soapui

I get the following error in SoapUi in Windows 10:

> Error getting response: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I tried renaming jre to jre.ignore

```
{
    "ObjectClass": "cl_claim",
    "ExternalID": "2018JanR2",
    "Properties": {
      "0": "TWN Test10",
      "pd_description": "Shashi10",
      "pd_open": "true",
      "pd_incidentdate": "2017-11-10"
    }
}
```

Expected to get a success message but still getting the same error.

Is it due to some TLS changes made (I use windows 10. Does this apply to win10)?

Answer (score -1):

Go to menu `File -> Preferences -> Http Settings` and then look for `Socket Timeout`. Try increasing the value appropriately.

Save the preferences.

Try to the service again.

For more details refer to the documentation regarding the same [here](https://www.soapui.org/docs/preferences-and-settings.html)